# Why aren't the animations working for this 2D unity character controller script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have some code that makes a player move up, down, left, and right.

```cs
public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Animator animator;
    public SpriteRenderer sr;

    Vector2 movement;
    bool walking = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        //Inputs
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("up") || Input.GetKey("down")
        {
            walking = true;
        }
        else
        {
            walking = false;
        }

        Animate();
    }

    private void Animate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("down") && walking == false)
        {
            sr.flipX = false;
            animator.Play("idle_front");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("down") && walking)
        {
            sr.flipX = false;
            animator.Play("walk_front");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("up") && walking == false)
        {
            sr.flipX = false;
            animator.Play("idle_back");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("down") && walking)
        {
            sr.flipX = false;
            animator.Play("walk_back");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("left") && walking == false)
        {
            sr.flipX = false;
            animator.Play("idle_side");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("down") && walking)
        {
            sr.flipX = false;
            animator.Play("walk_side");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("right") && walking == false)
        {
            sr.flipX = true;
            animator.Play("idle_side");
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("right") && walking)
        {
            sr.flipX = true;
            animator.Play("walk_side");
        }

    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Movement
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

The movement is working perfectly fine, but the character just stays in it's idle state. 
I have tried switching the get keys in `Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("up") || Input.GetKey("down")` to `Input.GetKeyDown()` and `Input.GetKeyUp()`, but none of that works.

I have also tried using Blend Trees, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I'm fairly new to Unity so a simple answer would be great.

Comment: Before asking please read [Question Asking Guideline] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Regarding to question, there are tons of youtube videos. Did you try any of them? with just 3 word you could find solution. Here is link to one of them. [Unity 2D Character Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA)

Answer (score 0):

open animator window

create 'State'

set animation clip into 'motion'

on top left click 'parameters' tab

click on plus sign next to parameters

click on 'Trigger'

name your trigger

right click on 'Any State' and make transition to drag a line to the new 'State' you created

click on the line between 'Any State' and the 'State' you created

under 'conditions' press the plus sign and add the trigger you just created

in code write

```
animator.SetTrigger("triggername");
```

when you want to transition to the before-mentioned animation state
repeat for all your animations, link them all from 'any state'